# Not able to change the postion of items in hive database

Tags: flutter, dart

Not able to swap the position of the record in hive database
getting error like Unhandled Exception: HiveError: The same instance of an HiveObject cannot be stored with two different keys ("5" and "10").

code:

```
  Box<CounterDetails> box = await Hive.openBox<CounterDetails>(kHiveBoxName);

 if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
   newIndex -= 1;
 }
// this is required, before you modified your box;
final oldItem = box.getAt(oldIndex);
final newItem = box.getAt(newIndex);

// here you just swap this box item, oldIndex <> newIndex
box.putAt(oldIndex, newItem!);
box.putAt(newIndex, oldItem!);
```

Comment: what is the dataType of oldItem?

Comment: its CounterDetails class object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the error, you can create `copyWith` method on `CounterDetails` that will return new instance. Or create new instance duplicating  fields. Then put this new object.

The copyWith method will be like

```dart
class CounterDetails {
  final String a;
  CounterDetails({
    required this.a,
  });


  CounterDetails copyWith({
    String? a,
  }) {
    return CounterDetails(
      a: a ?? this.a,
    );
  }
}
```

And putting those will be like

```dart
box.putAt(oldIndex, newItem!.copyWith()); //better do a null check 1st , same for next  one
```

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/README?id=initialize

Use `await Hive.initFlutter();` for **Flutter** apps.

Use `Hive.init()` for **non-Flutter** apps.